# The [writing] is on the wall

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing)

289 questions, no excerpt, and many of them seem to be in want of the clearer [file-writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-writing) tag instead, although the latest [wants to know how to get mad writing skills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983494/writing-skills-like-msdn) and there's a [few who just want to write code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724216/how-to-write-to-a-java-resource-file-works-in-ide-but-not-from-jar-file). It's just too ambiguous a tag.

I'm proposing a short burn and then synonymizing this to [file-writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-writing).

Comment: This tag's removal is in [writing]...

Comment: Pens (keyboards?) down, no more [writing]

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code [writing] service!

Answer (score 25):

I think that a retag is enough here, and a full scaled burnination is not needed.

Out of the 287 questions,

- 104 are also tagged with [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file), the top related tag for the [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing+file. These can be easily retagged to use [file-writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-writing).
- 110 are not tagged with [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file), but contain the word "file" in the body: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwriting%5D+-%5Bfile%5D+%22file%22++is%3Aq. These again can be retagged to [file-writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-writing), but would need a small intervention before retagging

The remaining 73 are the problematic ones [which are mostly related to "writing code"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=%5bwriting%5d%20-%5bfile%5d%20-"file"%20is%3aq). These ones need to be cleaned up. They need to either drop the tag [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing) or be closed.

Anyway to answer the 4 questions for burnination:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Even though writing describes the contents of the questions, it is not unambiguous, as we don't know if it is related to file writing or screen writing. I would go with a partial no as the answer to this question.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes, it is on-topic for the site. In fact just 15 questions are closed in the tag, as of now. (Though "writing code" sounds a lot like "gimmetehcodez", many questions are well-formed and quite on topic here)

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

It does add information to the post, and mentions that the question is related to "writing". However, giving the ambiguity of the tag, we are not clear about what "writing" the tag refers to, so it isn't that helpful.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, writing can be related to just "writing the code", or "writing to a file", in common context, and therefore doesn't mean the same thing.

From this it is clear that, the issue with the tag is mostly related to ambiguity and a retagging effort is all that is needed.